# Foreign Key Error - Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have these two tables:

`CREATE TABLE tbl_member (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  MemberNo varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  Surname varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  GivenNames varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);`

`CREATE TABLE tbl_sale (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TxnType smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  SalesID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Reference int(11) NOT NULL,
  TxnDate datetime NOT NULL,
  MemberID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  KEY MemberIDX (MemberID),
  KEY TxnDateIDX (TxnDate)
);`

But whenever I try to add this

`ALTER TABLE tbl_sale ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_sale_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES tbl_member (ID);`

I am getting this error

`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I don't understand why I am getting this error, 
Any help is appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to have `MemberID int(11) DEFAULT NULL`. It must be `NOT NULL`.